# How can I get a link to a specific email thread (a.k.a. conversation) in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook.com

How can I get a link to a specific email thread (a.k.a. conversation) in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

For example, in Gmail one get a link to a specific email thread by simply looking at the address bar of the web browser, such as https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox/15f1abab5c91bbae (the link is only accessible to the Gmail user who received email, that's fine for my use case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update (2022-03-03): one can get a link to a specific email thread in Microsoft Outlook web interface by simply looking at the address bar of the web browser, e.g.
https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox/id/AAQkAGJmMDZlZTQwLTFkYzgtNZJhMC04NGFjLTIwM2M3MmRjZTcwNQAQAGacsLcafdlFt8cUKmcBRag%3D

---

<s>The Microsoft Outlook web interface currently cannot provide a link to a specific email thread.</s>